# How to use Gorilla Mux to match entire path with regex

Tags: go, gorilla

I would like to be able to use regex to match the entire path not just a portion of it.

For Example:

```
/users.*
```

would match

```
/users
/users/bob
/users/bob/repos
```

Currently with Mux's `HandleFunc` you would have to match multiple paths

```
/users
/users/{.*}
/users/{.*}/{.*}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing my own custom matcher function and used go's regex package. It was very easy to do and here is an example:

```
import (
  ...
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "regexp"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  ...
)

...

muxRouter := mux.NewRouter()

muxRouter.
  Methods("GET", "POST").
  Schemes("https").
  MatcherFunc(func(r *http.Request, rm *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
    match, _ := regexp.MatchString("/users.*", r.URL.Path)
    // TODO handle error from regex
    return match
  }).
  HandlerFunc(m.ServeHTTP)
```

**The key is to use:**
`HandlerFunc(f func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request))`

**and not:**
`HandleFunc(path string, f func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request))`.

`HandlerFunc` must come after your matchers. This will allow you to write your own custom matcher function.

**Performance**
For my use case this performs well, but if you want better performance you could try using a precompiled `r, _ := regexp.Compile("p([a-z]+)ch")`.

You would probably need to use a struct with a `f func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)` that already has a precompile regex pattern stored in the struct.

**Go Regex Examples:**
https://gobyexample.com/regular-expressions

Go to Town! Hope you guys find this helpful.

Comment: There are plenty HTTP routers around there, which are more secure and more efficient. You can find a small list under http://awesome-go.com/#middlewares.
Problem with your implementation: Possibility to render arbitrary files (/users/../../../../etc/passwd)

Comment: Thanks for the resource I will check that out.For my use case it is an internal tool, and it isn't serving  static files, it is just matching an incoming path and calling a provided ResponseWriter. Can you clarify why this answer is not secure?

I also mentioned performance in my answer.